# How to update groupings via Mailchimp API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

I'm trying to subscribe and update members of a Mailchimp list from my Rails 3.2 app via the API.

Everything is working fine, except that I am unable to set interest groups.

What is the correct format for setting groupings.

I've tried

```
merge_vars: 'GROUPINGS'  => [
  [ 
    'id' => group_id,
    'groups' => ['array', 'of', 'groups']
  ]
]
```

and

```
merge_vars: 'GROUPINGS'  => [
  [ 
    'id' => group_id,
    'groups' => "comma,separated,groups"
  ]
]
```

and

```
merge_vars: 'GROUPINGS'  => [
  0 => [ 
    'id' => group_id,
    'groups' => "comma,separated,groups"
  ]
]
```

and several other variations.

Nothing seems to work and the docs are unclear

Comment: Thanks @AndyHarvey had the same problem, your Q helped me get past it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Took me some time but I finnaly figured out the correct format :

```
@gb.lists.subscribe({:id => list_id,
                     :email => {:email => self.email},
                     :merge_vars => {:FNAME => self.firstname,
                                     :groupings => [{:id => grouping_id,
                                                     :groups => ["name","of","groups"]
                                                   }]
                                    },
                     :double_optin => false,
                     :send_welcome => false,
                     :update_existing => true})
```

I'm using rails 3.1.11 and gibbon 0.5.0

Hope this will help !

Comment: Exactly what I ended up doing! Apologies for the slow response

Comment: thanks, the issue I had was the `:groups => ["name","of","groups"]` was not an array when I sent it, you'd think Mailchimp would validate this better!?